# php datetime object 1960 year limitation

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to use php datetime object for handling dates.

Here is my code:

```
$date = new DateTime('01 Dec, 1969');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

The above code returns `2010-12-01`

But If I change year from 1969 to 1945 or anything less than 1960 then the code returns incorrect year. For example:

This code:

```
$date = new DateTime('01 Dec, 1950');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

returns
    2010-12-01

Comment: Please provide your PHP Version and Operating System, including CPU architecture.

Comment: php version 5.2.14 OS: Windows 7 IIS7.5

Comment: @user in your first example, did you mean 2010 or 1969?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is likely a bug. Consider filing it to the bugtracker](http://bugs.php.net/report.php).

When you change the input format to

```
$date = new DateTime('Dec 1st, 1950');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

PHP will correctly make this into

```
1950-12-01
```

See http://codepad.org/trFfB6Q1

---

As of PHP5.3, you can also use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create a date. This would work with your original DateTime string then:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M, Y', '01 Dec, 1950');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

See http://codepad.viper-7.com/08kK5M

Answer (score 0):

Given that this problem does not occur on my system (PHP5.3 on a windows machine)
I suggest you update to php 5.3.
There are no drawbacks and this is probably not the only bug you will run into.
I have tested different date formats('1969/12/1','01 Dec, 1969',..) and had no problems at all.
if the problem persist feel free to slap me ;)

Comment: try the second date. I think the OP mistyped the resulting date for the first one in the question.

Answer (score -3):

PHP's Datetime is based on a unix timestamp which started counting from 1st of january 1970.

You cannot use DateTime to acces a date before that.